# How to disable scroll gestures upper half of the singlechildscrollview

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector, singlechildscrollview

I am finding for good ideas to disable scroll gestures upper half of the singlechildscrollview.
My app has singlechildscrollview in full screen for scrollable full screen but I need to put another widget that has other gestures on its upper half.
If keeping enable its upper half of scroll gestures conflicts gesture of the another wiget.
Please help me if you have a nice ideas to solve this problem.
[image]

I tried the following idea but it could not work well.
On the its upper half, when onVerticalDragStart detected of GestureDetector on another widget, switching to disable scroll gestures by using NeverScrollableScrollPhysics propaty of singlechildscrollview.
And when onVerticalDragEnd detected, switching back to enable scroll gestures.
On the its lower half, scroll gestures keep always enable.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `AnotherWidget` with `IgnorePointer` widget

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read class document of IgnorePointer and understood that it can disable gestures of its child widget. But I need to disable the part of its parent widget gestures.

Comment: So wrap list into stack, draw square transparent container on upper part and wrap it with ignorepointer